# Spring Boot - NamedParameterJdbcTemplate giving incorrect count of rows affected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jdbc

In my DAO repository class below is the implementation

```java
//Return the number of rows affected
public int deleteFeed(long feedId) {
    String sqlQuery = "UPDATE feed SET trash = TRUE WHERE id = :id";
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("id", feedId);
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, paramSource);
}
```

For the same `feedId` passed every time, the count result comes as 1 for the number of rows affected. If I run the same query in MySQL workbench, I am getting 0 rows affected.

Note: I am pointing to same DB in app and workbench.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it returns 1 it is 1. That isn't wrong, I suspect what you are doing in the workbench is either a different database or not the same query/id.

Comment: My app is pointing to the correct DB.

Comment: I'm not saying your app isn't pointing to the correct DB, your workbench is probably pointing to a different DB, schema or your are executing a (ever so slightly) different query).

Comment: In Workbench also I am looking at the correct DB. Through my app, I am inserting a new record which gets reflected in my workbench too.

Comment: [autocommit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov please provide a detailed explanation